# Install and compile JacORB

Tags: java, ant, jacorb

I was following this tutorial to install JacORB [Tutorial](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/spin/projects/rtpm/CORBA_MODULES/JacORB.html). In the last step, when I want to compile it, I got this error

```
Buildfile: /Users/adm/Downloads/jacorb/build.xml

base-init:

init-properties:

init-path:

init-javac-common:

init-javac-jdk:

init-javac-j2me:

init:

src-check:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/adm/Downloads/jacorb/build.xml:21: Unable to find src files. Is this a binary distribution?
```

But if I try ant in a demo file it builde successfully. I don't have to do the last step in the tutorial ? The second question is how to excute the build file ? after I builded the hello demo, I tried "jaco build" but I got a java exception

```
jaco build
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: build
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: build
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have the binary distribution of JacORB.

Download the source distribution of JacORB instead. On [the JacORB Download page](http://www.jacorb.org/download.html), click the link for **Full source code**.

Answer (score 0):

Or see https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/ for the official source code.

I would recommend asking questions about JacORB on the jacorb-developer list (http://www.jacorb.org/contact.html)